# "el proveedor microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 no esta registrado" Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estoy intentando conectar una base de datos access a Visual Studio 2019 y cuando selecciono el tipo de base de datos, que es access y selecciono el archivo, al probar conexion me sale el error que he puesto en el título.

He descargado los drivers para todas las versiones de office, he probado compilando en x64, x86 y x32 y el error presiste.

El formato de la base de datos es .accdb y la version de office 2016.

¿A alguien mas que le haya pasado podría decirme como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias y buen dia :)

Comment: Lo pudiste resolver,yo tengo el mismo problema :(

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener instalado el `engine` de ese proveedor

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

o quizas

[Componente redistribuible del motor de base de datos de Microsoft Access 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

con estos vas a poder usar el proveedor `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` en el connection string

[Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/)

Nota: recuerda reiniciar la pc para que reconozca los componentes

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar AccessDatabaseEngine 2007 (única de 32 bits), no se soluciona ni con la versión 2016 ni 2010 si tienes instalado Office 2016 de 64 bits.

[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://download.cnet.com/2007-Office-System-Driver-Data-Connectivity-Components/3000-10254_4-75452798.html)

**Actualización:**

`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` no funciona con bases `accdb`, para ello se debe usar un proveedor más actual como `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0`

Comment: Me pregunto quién será la persona que le dio un punto negativo, me imagino que nunca prueba la solución que se recomienda, si por algo se da una soución es porque se la probó en vista que otras soluciones no funcionan o son a medias.